# Rails 4, use before action with parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So currently I have a `before_action` set up that checks if users are signed in before they can do certain things...

```
before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, :index, :destroy, :show]

...

def signed_in_user
  unless signed_in?
    store_location
    redirect_to signin_url 
    flash[:warning] = "Please sign in."
   end
 end
```

However, the one thing I want to change is that when a user tries to access a specific action without being signed in, I want the flash message to be a little more informative than just "Please sign in." I.e. "Please sign in to [do a certain action]".

How would I modify what I already have to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `action_name`

```
def signed_in_user
  unless signed_in?
    store_location
    redirect_to signin_url 

    if %w[edit update].include? action_name
      flash[:warning] = "Please sign in to edit records."
    else
      flash[:warning] = "Please sign in."
    end
  end
end
```